# Strange occurence of string "Putty"

Tags: c, putty

I am running a C program using putty (don't ask why) and it is working fine, except when I run a particular function, the string "PuTTy" appears at the end. This doesn't seem to be affecting anything much, but I am just curious if anyone knows why this is happening and what sort of error this might indicate.

Note: When I run the code in a Linux terminal, there is no error whatsoever.

Comment: Sounds like a buffer overflow or similar UB is causing you to print environment variables. Suggestion: run through valgrind.

Comment: There are also codes that cause the terminal, in this case PuTTY, to issue its name.

Comment: "PuTTy" is not part of the shell prompt is it?  Try running your program and piping the output to a file ("program 2>&1 | tee log") and see if the string appears in the log file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an issue with PuTTY caused by your program emitting the Control-E character.  From the [PuTTY FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-puttyputty):

> **A.7.12 When I cat a binary file, I get ‘PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY’ on my command
>   line.**
>
> Don't do that, then.
>
> This is designed behaviour; when PuTTY receives the character
>   Control-E from the remote server, it interprets it as a request to
>   identify itself, and so it sends back the string ‘PuTTY’ as if that
>   string had been entered at the keyboard. Control-E should only be sent
>   by programs that are prepared to deal with the response. Writing a
>   binary file to your terminal is likely to output many Control-E
>   characters, and cause this behaviour. Don't do it. It's a bad plan.
>
> To mitigate the effects, you could configure the answerback string to
>   be empty (see [section 4.3.7](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-answerback)); but writing binary files to your
>   terminal is likely to cause various other unpleasant behaviour, so
>   this is only a small remedy.

Is your function outputting binary characters such as Control-E?

Comment: I would look into it.  In the 10 years I have been using PuTTY, the only time I have seen what you describe is when binary data is written to the terminal.

Comment: Oh yes! On capturing a detailed log, it seems that the function is indeed outputting binary characters (although its not supposed to but thats another matter). That should be the problem then and I can look to see how to fix that. Thanks!